# How to sum specific elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to manipulate an array. For each operation, I need to add a value to each the array element between two given indices, inclusive. Here is one example:

```js
0 1 100  // From index 0 to 1, add 100
1 4 100  // From index 1 to 4, add 100
2 3 100  // From index 2 to 3, add 100

// Expected Result:
[100, 200, 200, 200, 100]

// Explanation:
[100, 100] // After the first update.
[100, 200, 100, 100, 100] // After the second update.
[100, 200, 200, 200, 100] // After the third update.
```

And this was as far as I got:

```js
function arrayManipulation(n, queries) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    let indexIni = queries[i][0];
    let indexEnd = queries[i][1];
    let indexSum = queries[i][2];

    for (indexIni; indexIni < indexEnd; indexIni++) {
      console.log(indexIni, indexEnd, indexSum);
      newArr.splice(indexIni, 0, indexSum);
    }
  }
  console.log(newArr);
}

let n1 = 5;
let queries1 = [
  [0, 1, 100],
  [1, 4, 100],
  [2, 3, 100]
];
arrayManipulation(n1, queries1);
```

What I was trying to do was work on top of the second parameter of `splice()` so that I could somehow add it up to the number I was going to input.

The way I'm trying, is it possible? Or is there a simpler method?

Comment: Simpler method? Why can't you just traverse from indexIni to indexEnd and add indexSum to the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** loop should go upto

```
indexIni <= indexEnd
```

**2)** Iterating from the start and checking if any number is present on that particular index or not. If it does then add the `indexSum` else set the value as `indexSum`.

```js
function arrayManipulation(n, queries) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    let [indexIni, indexEnd, indexSum] = queries[i];

    for (indexIni; indexIni <= indexEnd; indexIni++) {
      if (newArr[indexIni]) {
        newArr[indexIni] += indexSum;
      } else {
        newArr[indexIni] = indexSum;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(newArr);
}

let n1 = 5;
let queries1 = [
  [0, 1, 100],
  [1, 4, 100],
  [2, 3, 100],
];
arrayManipulation(n1, queries1);
```

Comment: Pretty solution! Exactly what I need. Thanks!!

Comment: You probably need to initialize the array as well because if some of the indexes are missing from the operations then those elements in the array won't be defined

Comment: @ParagGangil That's why I've used the `if (newArr[indexIni])` condition.

Comment: @ParagGangil I agree there will be empty items, but OP doesn't say about that so why to worry...

Comment: This is true, and I had problems with this. I solved part of this specifying the size of array: `newArr = n` and filling it with zeros: `newArr.fill(0)`. I am doing some tests here.

Comment: We have to first find the highest number and then fill it will zero instead I would prefer to filter the final result as `newArr = newArr.filter((n) => n);`. This will remove all the empty item.

Answer (score 2):

Using `forEach` and `Array.from`

```js
function arrayManipulation(data) {
  const res = [];
  data.forEach(([start, end, value]) => {
    Array.from({ length: end - start + 1 }, (_, i) => start + i).forEach(
      (index) => (res[index] = (res[index] ?? 0) + value)
    );
  });
  return res;
}

const data = [
  [0, 1, 100],
  [1, 4, 100],
  [2, 3, 100],
];

console.log(arrayManipulation(data));
```